# Set margins for all children nodes in fxml

Tags: layout, javafx, fxml

I have a FXML layout file where the root element is a VBox. I want to set vertical margins/padding between each immediate child element within the VBox.

How do I accomplish this? Do I use a css, or is there XML tags I can use in the FXML file?

```
<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <HBox prefWidth="200.0">
        <Label text="Name:" />
        <TextField fx:id="nameTextField" />
  </HBox>
  <ChoiceBox fx:id="sampleEntryMode" />
  ...
</VBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [VBox.spacing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#spacingProperty) to add some space between each direct child.